# running fuzzywuzzy ratio over pandas single column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, similarity, fuzzywuzzy

I have a big list of full names example:

```
datafile.csv:
full_name, dob,
Jerry Smith,21/01/2010
Morty Smith,18/06/2008
Rick Sanchez,27/04/1993
Jery Smith,27/12/2012
Morti Smith,13/03/2012
```

I'm trying to use `fuzz.ration` to see if the names in column['fullname'] have any similarities, but code takes forever, mostly because of the nested for loop.

sample code:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv')
_list = []
for row1 in dataframe['fullname']:
    for row2 in dataframe['fullname']:
        x = fuzz.ratio(row1, row2)
        if x > 90:
            _list.append([row1, row2, x])

print(_list)
```

Is there a better method to iterate of a single pandas column to get a ratio for potential duplicate data?

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 0):

You can create first fuzzy data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

data = StringIO("""
Jerry Smith
Morty Smith
Rick Sanchez
Jery Smith
Morti Smith
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, names=['full_name'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df[row['full_name']] = df['full_name'].apply(lambda x:fuzz.ratio(row['full_name'], x))

print(df.to_string())
```

**Output:**

```
      full_name  Jerry Smith  Morty Smith  Rick Sanchez  Jery Smith  Morti Smith
0   Jerry Smith          100           73            26          95           64
1   Morty Smith           73          100            26          76           91
2  Rick Sanchez           26           26           100          27           35
3    Jery Smith           95           76            27         100           67
4   Morti Smith           64           91            35          67          100
```

Then find best match for selected name:

```
data_rows = df[df['Jerry Smith'] > 90]
print(data_rows)
```

**Output:**

```
     full_name  Jerry Smith  Morty Smith  Rick Sanchez  Jery Smith  Morti Smith
0  Jerry Smith          100           73            26          95           64
3   Jery Smith           95           76            27         100           67
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from fuzzywuzzy import process

s = """full_name,dob
Jerry Smith,21/01/2010
Morty Smith,18/06/2008
Rick Sanchez,27/04/1993
Jery Smith,27/12/2012
Morti Smith,13/03/2012"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

# 1 - use fuzzywuzzy.process.extract with list comprehension
# 2 - You still have to iterate once but this method avoids the use of apply, which can be very slow
# 3 - convert the list comprehension results to a dataframe 
# Note that I am limiting the results to one match. You can adjust the code as you see fit
df2 = pd.DataFrame([process.extract(df['full_name'][i], df[~df.index.isin([i])]['full_name'], limit=1)[0] for i in range(len(df))],
                   index=df.index, columns=['match_name', 'match_percent', 'match_index'])
# join the new dataframe to the original
final = df.join(df2)


      full_name         dob   match_name  match_percent  match_index
0   Jerry Smith  21/01/2010   Jery Smith             95            3
1   Morty Smith  18/06/2008  Morti Smith             91            4
2  Rick Sanchez  27/04/1993  Morti Smith             43            4
3    Jery Smith  27/12/2012  Jerry Smith             95            0
4   Morti Smith  13/03/2012  Morty Smith             91            1
```

Comment: At least for me this performs magnitudes slower (with the example data used here your solution is around 50 times slower than the one used in the question)

Comment: @maxbachmann `fuzzywuzzy.process.extract` is the slow part not the use of list comprehension. Make sure you are using `python-Levenshtein` when executing.

Comment: Yes this was no proper test, but even with a lot of elements it is still a lot slower (btw it does not matter whether it is using python-Levenshtein or not, since this would affect both in the same way)
btw the question does not limit to one result like you do, but even when you want to do this you should probably use process.extractOne ;)

Answer (score 0):

This comparison method is doing double work since running fuzz.ratio between "Jerry Smith" and "Morti Smith" is the same as between "Morti Smith" and "Jerry Smith".

If you iterate through a sub array then you will be able to complete this faster.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv')
_list = []
for i_dataframe in range(len(dataframe)-1):
    comparison_fullname = dataframe['fullname'][i_dataframe]
    for entry_fullname, entry_score in process.extract(comparison_fullname, dataframe['fullname'][i_dataframe+1::], scorer=fuzz.ratio):
        if entry_score >=90:
            _list.append((comparison_fullname, entry_fullname, entry_score)
print(_list)
```

This will prevent any duplicate work.

Comment: limit=90 means that the 90 best results will be returned. This is something completely different to the check whether the score is over 90 that is used in the question

Comment: Beside this you should access dataframe['fullname'][i_dataframe] instead of dataframe[i_dataframe]['fullname'] ( same in the next line + there is a missing clossing bracket)

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two parts that can help you to improve the performance:

1. reduce the amount of comparisions
2. use a faster way to match the strings

In your implementation your performing a lot of unrequired comparisions, since your always comparing A <-> B and later on B <-> A. Your comparing A <-> A aswell, which is generally always 100. So you can reduce the amount of comparisions by more than 50%. Since you only want to add matches with a score of over 90, this information can be used to speed up the comparisions. While this can not be done in FuzzyWuzzy, it can be done in [Rapidfuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz) (I am the author). Rapidfuzz implements the same algorithms as FuzzyWuzzy with a relatively similar interface, but has a lot of performance improvements.

Your code could be implemented the following way to implement those two changes, which should be a lot faster. When testing this on my machine this runs around 12 seconds with your code, while this improved version only requires 1.7 seconds.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from rapidfuzz import fuzz

# generate a bigger list of examples to show the performance benefits
s = "fullname,dob"
s+='''
Jerry Smith,21/01/2010
Morty Smith,18/06/2008
Rick Sanchez,27/04/1993
Jery Smith,27/12/2012
Morti Smith,13/03/2012'''*500

dataframe = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

# only create the data series once
full_names = dataframe['fullname']
for index, row1 in full_names.items():
    # skip elements that are already compared
    for row2 in full_names.iloc[index+1::]:
        # use a score_cutoff to improve the runtime for bad matches
        score = fuzz.ratio(row1, row2, score_cutoff=90)
        if score:
            _list.append([row1, row2, score])
```